# Google Drive API - Crash when setting permissions

Tags: php, google-api, permissions, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

I'm using the Google Drive api for php and trying to copy files to a specific folder and give them permissions.

When i try to execute it with debugger on no problem, the rights are set to the good users. But when i try to execute it "normally" the results are never the same and it seems to crash (or timeout) when setting the rights.

This my code :

```
function deleteFilePermissions($fileId)
{
    global $driveService;

    $results = $driveService->permissions->listPermissions($fileId, array(
        'fields' => 'nextPageToken, permissions(id, role, emailAddress)'
    ));

    foreach ($results->getPermissions() as $permission) {
        if ($permission->getRole() != 'owner'
        && $permission->getEmailAddress() != 'noreply@opportunities-fo-1541429464609.iam.gserviceaccount.com')
            $driveService->permissions->delete($fileId, $permission->getId());
    }
}

function changeFileRights($fileId, $rights, $emailAddresses)
{
    global $driveService;

    deleteFilePermissions($fileId);
    foreach ($rights as $key => $right) {
        $userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
            'type' => 'user',
            'role' => $right,
            'emailAddress' => $emailAddresses[$key]
        ));
        $request = $driveService->permissions->create($fileId, $userPermission, array(
            'fields' => 'id',
            'sendNotificationEmail' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

This is the function call:

```
changeFileRights($fileId, ['reader', 'writer'], ['email1@gmail.com', 'email2@gmail.com']);
```

Comment: who are you logged in as when you try to do this change permission?

Comment: I am logged as a service account which has already right on the folder

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i managed to do it by increasing the max execution limit of my php.ini. The execution was just too long, and that's why it did not give me the same result every time.